# User Authentication with spring 3.0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I tried searching in Google, but I could not find any good examples where a username and password are checked with a database for authentication purposes.

In further simple words, how can I create a simple login form using Spring and Hibernate and NOT SPRING SECURITY where the credentials are checked with the database.

Please help me creating a simple login form with just Spring 3.0 and no Spring Security 3.0. Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone come up with a simple example where I can see how the flow goes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to do a login form post to a Spring Controller which take username and password as parameter.

In the controller you do what ever you want to authenticate the username and password. Best is to delegate to some service layer which takes care of it.

If successfully authenticated then what you want to do? May be redirect to say home page.

Now the home page rendering should know that the user is already authenticated. This is where spring security helps.

But you can also achieve by writing a Servlet Filter where you check if user is already authenticated by checking the http session. Of course after successful login you need to store that in the session then only it will be available to the filter.

There are many other ways to achieve the same which depends upon your requirement as in what kind of security control is required.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution has two parts, one of which involves Spring and another that is your code:

```
// DAO returns null if no such username appears in the table.
String password = userDao.findPassword(username);
boolean isValidUser = (!password.equals(null));
// Write the code to implement behavior for valid and invalid users.
```

If you can do a database SELECT for a password, you can do Spring authentication without Spring Security.

You may need to put that logic in an aspect that's woven in before method calls.

You may want to cache that result in session and invalidate it if a timeout is exceeded.